# Cron Magento2 didn't work

Tags: magento2, cron, log

I have created a new module with my `crontab.xml` :

```
<config>
    <group id="default">
        <job name="order_read" instance="Cincuenta\CronOrders\Model\Orders" method="readOrders">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Also i got a `CronOrders/Model/Orders.php` with the function :

```
public function readOrders(){


        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/loggy.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('LOG1');
...
```

I had try to run by command with

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

and

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group:"default"
```

But the log is not been created.
I also tested my log code and it runs in others functions well.

Any error with the crons in Magento 2 or I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you try run `cron:run` two times?

Comment: I had already runned cron:run like 100 times trying to get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [magerun](https://files.magerun.net/) for testing out your cron code.

Just download it to the root folder of your project and then run

`php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:list` to get a list of all registered crons

`php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run [cron code]` to run a specific cron job

It has all sort of magento2 utility commands as well, just run

`php n98-magerun2.phar` to get a list of all available commands

Hope this helps !!

Comment: super buddy. it is very very useful !!!! :-)

Comment: Working Sir Ji.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i missed some code on `crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="order_read" instance="Cincuenta\CronOrders\Model\Orders" method="readOrders">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

I added in `<config>` this line:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd
```