# Magento 2: Cron logs not generated

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

Below cron setting worked in **Magento 2.0.1** (fedora 22)

`$ crontab -u www-data -e`

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini /var/www/public/bin/magento cron:run >> /var/www/public/var/log/magento.cron.log&

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini /var/www/public/update/cron.php >> /var/www/public/var/log/update.cron.log&

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini /var/www/public/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/public/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

When I configure the same in **Magento 2.0.8** (Ubuntu 16.04 - docker container). When I run cron it does not generate log file but it gives success message **Ran jobs by schedule.**  I have checked with `cron_schedule` table it gets update whenever I run cron manually. It is not yet run as per scheduled every one minute.

any changes in 2.0.8 cron configuration? am I missing something?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/114344/36463 this answer solved my custom cron job problem. I don't know why the above method is not work in 2.0.8.